# Need help editing code to rotate on keyboard instead of scrollwheel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am currently using a code that allows me to rotate a 3d object I place into a scene but want to use the keyboard to rotate the object instead of the scroll wheel as it interferes with a script I am using for Zooming in and out.

I have already set the scrollwheel rotation to 0 so it not longer rotates the object but am struggling on how to implement a code that allows me to use the keyboard instead.

Since I am still very  new  at C# I am struggling greatly with how to do this and am having a hard time finding free resources to learn the language.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GroundPlacementTest : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private GameObject placeableObjectPrefab;

[SerializeField]
private KeyCode newObjectHotkey = KeyCode.A;

private GameObject currentPlaceableObject;

private float mouseWheelRotation;

private void Update()
{
    HandleNewObjectHotkey();

    if (currentPlaceableObject != null)
    {
        MoveCurrentObjectToMouse();
        RotateFromMouseWheel();
        ReleaseIfClicked();
    }
}

private void HandleNewObjectHotkey()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(newObjectHotkey))
    {

        if (currentPlaceableObject != null)
        {
            Destroy(currentPlaceableObject);
        }
        else
        {
            currentPlaceableObject = Instantiate(placeableObjectPrefab);
            currentPlaceableObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");
        }
    }
}

private void MoveCurrentObjectToMouse()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
    {
        currentPlaceableObject.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
        currentPlaceableObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);

    }
}

private void RotateFromMouseWheel()
{
    Debug.Log(Input.mouseScrollDelta);
    mouseWheelRotation += Input.mouseScrollDelta.y;
    currentPlaceableObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseWheelRotation * 0f);
}

private void RotateFromMouseWheel()
{
    Debug.Log(Input.mouseScrollDelta);
    mouseWheelRotation += Input.mouseScrollDelta.y;
    currentPlaceableObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseWheelRotation * 0f);
}

private void ReleaseIfClicked()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        currentPlaceableObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default");
        currentPlaceableObject = null;
    }
}
```

I want to use the keyboard to rotate the object instead of the scroll wheel rotating it.

Answer (score 0):

well instead of

```
private void RotateFromMouseWheel()
{
    Debug.Log(Input.mouseScrollDelta);
    mouseWheelRotation += Input.mouseScrollDelta.y;
    currentPlaceableObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseWheelRotation * 0f);
}
```

(which by the way you have twice there) you could use [`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)

```
// Set in the inspector
public float RotationSpeed;

private void RotateFromMouseWheel()
{
    // whatever key you want
    // this makes one rotation each click
    // if you want it continous see below
    if(!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) return;

    currentPlaceableObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, RotationSpeed);
}
```

or for continous rotation while button stays pressed [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) and [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

```
private void RotateFromMouseWheel()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
    {
        currentPlaceableObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

---

`am having a hard time finding free resources to learn the language`

you could e.g. have a look at one of the tutorials (these are the first three results when looking for "Unity keyboard input" on google ...) and have a look at the Unity API (see links above)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-hM-yzH_-E

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chMxcadsT4U

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0WZf1CmN3k

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply, I will look at those videos now (I think I may have been over complicating the search parameters).

Comment: I have used the above information but now the object snaps back to its original orientation after pressing the button. I am looking to smoothly rotate the object on its axis and stay in the orientation I rotate it to.

Comment: I'ld say that happens because you also change the rotation here `currentPlaceableObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);`

Comment: it still is not locking on and not rotating correctly